# Change the content of Countries.txt

Tags: maps, qt

I'm following the steps on this page:

"https://github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/master/docs/MAPS.md",

"https://github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md"

When I run this line "omim / tools / unix / generate_mwm.sh source.pbf any_random_string_asdf" I do not have an error, then I run qt and maps.me application is opened but when I click on the route nothing happens.

What do I have to do?

In this link "github.com/mapsme/omim/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md" , below the page says this:

The version and file sizes of all mwm and routing files should be put into data / countries.txt file.

I do not know what changes to make.

Comment: have you got anywhere with this?